# Alloy : Graph coloring

Tags: alloy

Here are the signatures :

```
abstract sig Color{}
lone sig Red, Blue, Yellow, Green extends Color{}

abstract sig Vertex{
  couleur: Color
}

abstract sig Digraph{
   vertices: set Vertex,
   edges: set(Vertex -> Vertex)
}
fact{
   vertices.couleur != edges.couleur
}
```

I get an error saying that I can't use "!=" between 2 expressions that aren't the same arity. I get why, but I don't know how I can solve this.

What I want to do is, forbidding the two vertices color to be the same in an edge. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple: the expression `vertices.couleur != edges.couleur` does not typecheck since `vertices` and `edges`, and thus also the operands of `!=`, are of different arity. (Essentially, you are trying to compare a set of `Color` to a set of `(Color -> Vertex)`.)

As an example, if you take the image of the edges relation (by projecting it onto the universal set), you will not get the error:

```
fact {
   vertices.couleur != edges.univ.couleur
}
```

(For more info about the basic operators in Alloy, it would be useful to check the tutorial and/or the Alloy book.)